# Explanation of code QSORT code in C

Tags: c

I am new to StackOverflow. In fact I created it just to ask this question.

My prof lightly glazed over a slide containing the following code, and everyone was lost, myself included.

```
   main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int nlines; /* number of input lines read */

    int numeric = 0; /* 1 if numeric sort */

    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0)
      numeric = 1;
    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) 
    {
      qsort((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,
      (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
      writelines(lineptr, nlines);
      return 0;
    } 
    else 
    { ...}
}
```

Can you give a detailed explanation on what the hell is going on?

Comment: I would say this is the source code of the `sort` command, only obfuscated to hold on a slide and avoiding the interesting sorting part :)

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Would it be better to ask the prod.  He is getting paid to help you

Comment: Please, pick a language, proofread what you write (hope that doesn't need an explamtation) and format your code legibly.

Comment: And what had your prof to say about this piece of code ?

Comment: Sorry I only posted it exactly as he did without formatting. I asked him but his explanation was as confusing as the code. We just learned about pointers and memory alloc that same class, and this partical example (Pointers to pointers) is not even in the textbook

Comment: Can I get a percentage of his salary

Comment: @EdHeal I wouldn't pay him much if he really shows poorly formatted code as this one.

Comment: @Tee read about function pointers and qsort. There are tons of documentation out there. BTW there are lots of parts missing in your code (such as `readlines`and `writelines`.

Comment: `qsort` takes a function argument, which is your own function used to make the comparisons needed by `qsort`. It is done like this because only you know what the array contains, and how to sort it, while `qsort` deals with the mechanics of the sorting itself. That function argument given here to `qsort`, uses the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) controlled by `numeric`, to decide which sorting function to use. That depends ultimately on the program argument `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

`nlines` tracks the number of lines that are read from input.
`numeric` keeps track of if numbers are being sorted (as opposed to characters).

The rest of my explanation is within the comments:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int nlines; /* number of input lines read */

    int numeric = 0; /* 1 if numeric sort */

    /* evaluates whether or not numeric sorting is to be applied */
    if (argc > 1 && strcmp(argv[1], "-n") == 0)
      numeric = 1;

    /* this reads lines if there are any.*/
    /* it looks like `lineptr` must've been declared elsewhere */
    if ((nlines = readlines(lineptr, MAXLINES)) >= 0) 
    {
      qsort((void**) lineptr, 0, nlines-1,
      (int (*)(void*,void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp));
      /* sort the elements accordingly... e.g., either as strings or numerically. */


      writelines(lineptr, nlines);
      return 0;
    }

    /* else gets run if there is no input to take */
    else 
    { ...}
}
```